# Blank screen with blinking cursor while trying live usb install of Win 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, usb-boot, repair-install, rufus

I had my laptop running on Windows 10 set for update and restart. While updating the system crashed and the blue screen waiting for restart came. When restarted the system goes to Windows automatic repair and then again to the blue screen for restart. This keeps happening. So I decided to to do a windows repair. I went on to make a usb boot disk using unetbootin. But after selecting the usb in boot disk selection it shows missing operating system. So I tried to create boot disk using Rufus. This time after selecting usb from boot disk menu the screen becomes blank with just a blinking cursor. I tried it on my desktop. Then also the same thing happened. I changed the windows 10 iso file and created another usb boot disk. But no change. What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the partition scheme in Rufus from default GPT to MBR.